# About "this" in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var name = "the Window.";
var object = {
    name:"Object",
    getName: function(){
        return this.name;
    }
}
(object.getName)(); //"Object"
(object.getName = object.getName)(); //"the Window"
```

I run this code, and it return "the Window", while i think it should be "Object".Please tell me why? thanks.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: The value of *this* inside a function depends on *how it is called*, not *how or where it is defined*. `this` must definitely be the most talked about thing in SO.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword

Comment: @AurA—a little weird that MDN categorises *this* as an operator. It's a keyword.

Comment: Please also consider strict mode where when a function is not called with a specific context or by the owner object, `this` is undefined and not a fallback to the global context.

Answer (score 3):

```
var name = "the Window.";
```

Global declarations create a property of the global/window object. This is equivalent (more or less) to:

```
var global = this;
global.name = 'the Window';
```

The expression:

```
(object.getName = object.getName)
```

returns the function referenced by `object.getName`. The following empty parameter list (i.e. the `()`) causes it to be called.

Since the *this* value is not set by the call, it defaults to the global/window object, so the function returns the value of *global.name*.

Comment: but why (object.getName)() return "Object"?

Comment: Because when you call the function as a method of `object`, its `this` references `object`. So `this.name` returns `object.name`, which is the string "Object". Perhaps you should use some different values to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

The bottom line of confusion is we are trying to execute

```
(object.getName = object.getName)();
```

and we think it should print "Object".

Actually, it won't. Here is a simple reason. If you break this statement into 2 statements you will get it.

- Assignment: object.getName is assigned some handler. In this case, it is assigned to itself.
- Execution of handler. Now, the handler is exected but we do not have context this time. Handler is executed by window. So you are getting window.name which is 'the window.'

Try this

```
var x = object.getName;
x();
```

It is somewhat similar to your case and it gives 'the window.' too for the same reason x is executed by window.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of thinking of `this` in the classic OOP way you're used to, think of `this` as the context on which a function is called.

In your sample code, `window` is the context for the `getName` call, regardless of where that function is declared.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = object.getName;
x();
```

is not quite the same.
the "=" only make sure that x refer to the same memory address as object.getName, but x belongs to window while object.getName belongs to object.
I think the problem comes from the return value of the assignment expression.
maybe there is a temporary variable to receive the value of (object.getName = object.getName), that is,

```
var temp = (object.getName = object.getName);
temp();//"the Window"
```

thus may make sense.